# PyQt - Action Only Producing Last Value

Tags: python, user-interface, debugging, pyqt, pyqt4

Below is my code for part of an analytics GUI. When a country in the menu is clicked a menu distinct to that country should be produced. At the moment, however, whatever country is pressed the last country will be the one who's menu is produced (in this case clicking on either country will produce a Netherland's menu). Why is this?

```
import csv
import math
import itertools
import numpy as np
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def countryAction(self):

        window = QtGui.QMainWindow(self)
        window.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)
        window.setWindowTitle(self.tr(country))
        window.show()

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setGeometry(50, 50, 500, 300)
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle('uAnalytics')
        MainWindow.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('uTalkLogo.png'))

        self.menubar = QtGui.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 867, 22))
        self.menubar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("menubar"))
        self.menuCountry = QtGui.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuCountry.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("menuCountry"))
        self.menuPopular_Countries = QtGui.QMenu(self.menuCountry)
        self.menuPopular_Countries.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("menuPopular_Countries"))
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("statusbar"))
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.actionAll_Countries = QtGui.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionAll_Countries.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("actionAll_Countries"))
        self.menuCountry.addAction(self.actionAll_Countries)
        self.menuCountry.addSeparator()
        self.menuCountry.addAction(self.menuPopular_Countries.menuAction())

        continents = {}
        countries = {}
        popularcountries = ['United States', 'United Kingdom', 'South Africa', 'Germany', 'India', 'Australia', 'Canada', 'Italy', 'Sweden' ,\
    'Netherlands', 'France', 'New Zealand', 'Belgium', 'Switzerland', 'Norway', 'Brazil', 'Indonesia', 'Russia', \
    'United Arab Emirates', 'Spain', 'Denmark']
        DIR = '/Users/jonathan/Documents/CountryWiseAnalytics/'
        UsersCountry = {('Europe', 'NL', 'Netherlands'): 231, ('Europe', 'GB', 'United Kingdom'): 2636}
        for key, value in UsersCountry.iteritems():
            continent = key[0]
            continentMenu = continents.get(continent)
            if continentMenu is None:
                continentMenu = self.menuCountry.addMenu(continent)
                continents[continent] = continentMenu
            country = key[2]
            CT = key[1]
            countryAction = QtGui.QAction(QtGui.QIcon(CT.lower() + '.png'), country, MainWindow)
            countryAction.setStatusTip('uAnalyse ' + country)
            countryAction.triggered.connect(lambda: self.countryAction(country))
            if country in popularcountries:
                print(CT.lower() + '.png')
                self.menuPopular_Countries.addAction(countryAction)
            else:
                continentMenu.addAction(countryAction)

        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuCountry.menuAction())
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", None))
        self.menuCountry.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Country", None))
        self.menuPopular_Countries.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Popular Countries", None))
        self.actionAll_Countries.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "All Countries", None))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

There is not much to explain in this code. The error is likely somewhere in the block starting with continents = {} as this is where the countryAction is defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need to use partial rather than lambda

```
from functools import partial 
countryAction.triggered.connect(partial(self.countryAction, country))
```

Comment: Thanks, this works great. Could you explain the logic behind it? Is it something to do with the effect of lambda being that the function is only called upon being clicked and hence always triggers the last countryAction?

Comment: Yes, I would also like to know. Do lambda functions somehow not exist in all contexts?

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to work for me.  I'm on CentOS-7 on an x86_64:

jkelly@centos:~$ rpm -qi PyQt4
Version     : 4.10.1
Release     : 13.el7

Comment: It runs, but do you not get a window titled 'United Kingdom' whether you click on The Netherlands or the UK?

Comment: Right you are.  If I use a function to return the lambda, it works.
<pre>
    def cfunc(self, country):
        return lambda x: self.countryAction(country)

...
           countryAction.triggered.connect(self.cfunc(country))
</pre>

Comment: Also had to add country as an argument to self.countryAction